# authentication issues in sending email via python script

Tags: python-3.x

I followed below steps to send email with python script--

```
import smtplib
smtpUser='sint.15@gmail.com'
smtpPass='1234'
toAdd='ajit@gmail.com'
fromAdd=smtpUser
subject='Python test'
header='To:' +toAdd+'\n'+'From:'+fromAdd+'\n' +'Subject:'+ subject
body='From within a python script'

print( header + '\n'+ body)
s= smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()
s.login(smtpUser,smtpPass)
s.sendmail(fromAdd,toAdd,header +'\n' + body)
s.quit()
```

then the error msg is--

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/129/PycharmProjects/smtp.py", line 34, in    <module>
s.login(smtpUser,smtpPass)
File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\smtplib.py", line 652, in login
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (501, b'5.5.2 Cannot Decode response q9sm74360527pfg.47 - gsmtp')
Process finished with exit code 1
```

can someone please explain me what is the error, if I am not wrong it is related to google security.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to send an email from a gmail account:

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
s.starttls()
s.login(username, password)
s.sendmail(from_mail, to_mail, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html). It worked for me.